Unable to authenticate a user from React with Spring Boot Spring Security
I have been trying to authenticate the user using React Login form, But don't know why I can't able to authenticate it or redirect to some location in my react app via server (Spring boot)
React Code,
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Button } from "./OverrideComponents/Button";


export default function Login(){

    let [username,setUsername]=useState('')
    let [password,setPassword]=useState('')

    let formSubmit=async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(username,password)

        const login=await fetch("http://localhost:5001/login",{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({username,password})
        })
        console.log(login)

        const data= await login.json();
        console.log(data)
        if (login.ok) {
            // Redirect or update state for authenticated user
            console.log("login success")
            // window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5001/test/x';// route at my server
        } else {
            console.log('Login failed. Please check your credentials.');
        }
    }



    return(
        <>
            <form onSubmit={formSubmit} method="post" action="login">
                <label htmlFor="username">Name</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value={username} onChange={e=>setUsername(e.target.value)} />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password" />
                {/* <button type="submit">Login</button> */}
                <Button>Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

Routing below:

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1> Hello Welcome home </h1>} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<h1> Hello Welcome ContactPage </h1>} />
          <Route path="/work" element={<h1> Hello Welcome WorkPage </h1>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Login></Login>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

My Spring Boot Code be as,
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:5173")
class ControllerTest{

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/test/x")
    String testx(@RequestParam(required = false) String msg) {
    String header="{'ab':'xyx'}";
    byte []b=header.getBytes();
    String encoded=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b);
    System.out.println(encoded);
    if (msg == null) {
        return "Null Msg";
    }
    return "this is my Testingx -> " + msg;
}

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("/login")
    UserDetails userLogin(@RequestBody UserDetail user) {
    System.out.println(user.getUsername()+"  --  "+user.getPassword());
        
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    System.out.println(authentication);
    return user;
    }
}

Here is my Spring Security class
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigTest {
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //Authentication
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .requestMatchers("/user/**","/login","/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );
    http.csrf(csrf->csrf.disable());
    http.formLogin(formlogin->formlogin.loginPage("http://localhost:5173")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:5713/contact",true)
    );
    return http.build();
        
    }
@Bean
     UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder pa) {
    UserDetails user=User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(pa.encode("pass"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
    System.out.println("at userDetailsService");
        
    UserDetails user1=User.withUsername("user")
                .password(pa.encode("user"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user,user1);
    }
    @Bean
     public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      System.out.println("in DaoAuth");
      provider.setPasswordEncoder(passEnc());   
      return provider;
    }
}

I'm trying to authenticate the users who are defined in SecurityConfig class as InMemory Users and upon Authenticated, I want to access different routes as mentioned like /test/x from server and also wanted to redirect to /contact or /work on the Frontend React Side.
My Analysis,

Frontend:
Upon inspecting the my Login in React I realize for correct credentials I'm getting User object with no issues like below,

admin pass
Login.jsx:22 Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:5001/login', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
Login.jsx:25 {mail: null, username: 'admin', password: 'pass', roles: null, authorities: null, …}

but when I try with wrong credentials I get in console as,
localhost:5001 is for Spring boot, and localhost:5173 is for React
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5001/login' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
              
POST http://localhost:5001/login net::ERR_FAILED 401 (Unauthorized)


Server:
When I execute the React app, and pass the username and password and submit them, I see the output from System.out.println(authentication); at /login controller about the user but not my user is not getting authenticated.

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=admin, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]

So I suspect it is working in a way but not authenticating also not redirecting, don't know where is the mistake/issue.
